# OOP jQuery Plugin elem undefined in one place and not in others

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, jquery-plugins

How is my element undefined if I clearly define it here. It works in all the other methods but with exception of `setUpCalendar()`. I've included the "path" the code goes through before reaching the problematic part.

```
var Calendar = {

    init: function(options, elem) {

        this.options = $.extend( {}, this.options, options );
        this.elem = $(elem); //Clearly defined here and works elsewhere
        this.getFeed();

        return this;
    },

    getFeed: function() {
        var self = Calendar;
        $.jGFeed(this.options.feedUrl, function (feeds) {

            if (!feeds) {
                return false;
            }

            $.extend(self.entries, feeds.entries);

            self.parseEntries();
        }, 10);
    },

    parseEntries: function() {
        //Rename to fit plugin requirements
        for (var i = 0; i < Calendar.entries.length; i++) {
            var entry = Calendar.entries[i];
                entry["allDay"] = false;

            //Rename
            entry["url"] = entry["link"];
            delete entry["link"];
        };

        this.setUpCalendar();
    },

    setUpCalendar: function() {
        Calendar.elem.fullCalendar({ //It's telling me Calendar.elem is undefined here
            editable: false,
            weekends: false,
            events: Calendar.entries //funny story, here the reference works
        });
    }
};
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$.fn.ksdCalendar = function( options ) {
    if (this.length) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var myCalendar = Object.create(Calendar);
            myCalendar.init(options, this);
            $.data(this, 'ksdCalendar', myCalendar);
        });
    }
};

$("#calendar").ksdCalendar({
    feedUrl: "http://www.kent.k12.wa.us/site/RSS.aspx?DomainID=275&ModuleInstanceID=4937&PageID=4334"
});
```

Comment: Can you add the part where you call `init`?

Comment: Yeah, I think we're missing some code about how this object is initialized.

Comment: I've updated the question with the init call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem here is that you're mixing your `this` references and `Calendar` references. When you call `this.getFeed()` you're operating on a newly created `Calendar` object. Within `getFeed` though, however, you're setting `var self = Calendar` and subsequently using `self` to set the values for `entries` and call `parseEntries`.

What you've done here is create a reference (with `self`) to the global `Calendar` object literal. That object is not the object that you've initialized via `Object.create` (and it's not the one you called `init` on).

What this all boils down to is, you've initialized `myCalendar` and set up the `elem` that it's attached to, but in your subsequent method calls you set `entries` on the global `Calendar` object literal. Inside your `parseEntries` method, all of this becomes apparent because the current scope is inside that of the global `Calendar` object literal and not the instance of the `Calendar` object created and returned by `Object.create`.

To fix it, do `var self = this;` instead of `var self = Calendar;`. Within `parseEntries` reference `this.entries` instead of `Calendar.entries`, and in `setUpCalendar` reference `this.entries` and `this.elem` instead of `Calendar.entries` and `Calendar.elem` repsectively.

Answer (score 0):

In `init()` you're adding `elem` to `this`, that is `myCalendar`. In `setupCalendar()` you're trying to retrieve it from `Calendar` which doesn't seem to have the `elem` property (unless it's in a different portion of the code) even tho' it's the <del>constructor function</del> prototype for `myCalendar`.